# How do I succesfully import DSS Library?

Tags: java, maven, jetbrains-ide, e-signature

I have been trying to use the DSS library (as found in their git https://github.com/esig/dss) for an e-signature project. So far I have tried to manually download the Maven files and import them as external libraries, using JetBrains. I also tried opening the Maven files as new project. Last but not least I tried opening the Maven files through a new GitHub repository. The problem is that, whenever I'm loading a Maven file from the project, the imports seem to cannot be resolved.

In terms of troubleshooting I tried to use several IDEs and different installation and project paths, constantly updating and refreshing Maven repository, an occasionally tying to manually download some Maven libraries from the Maven repository.

Please find below some screenshots of the errors:

[image: Errors during imports]

Pom.xml errors:

[image: Pom.xml errors]

JUnit error:

[image: JUnit error]

Comment: Have you added the repository `https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/artifact/content/repositories/esignaturedss/` to your `settings.xml` or `pom.xml` (as described in the github link you gave us)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to access to the original files of DSS project? For general use of the library, you may use it as a dependency without downloading the source code, unless you want to fork it and make some modifications.

For integrations instructions please see the [documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#_integration_instructions).

First of all you will need to add the DSS repository to the pom.xml file of your Maven project:

```
<repositories>
    ...

    <repository>
      <id>cefdigital</id>
      <name>cefdigital</name>
      <url>https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/artifact/content/repositories/esignaturedss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After you will need to add the required modules as dependencies to the project. Information about the modules you may also find in the documentation.

I hope this will help you.

Best regards,
Aleksandr.